# google street view on a mobile

Tags: google-maps

Does anyone know why the same iframe embedded Google streetview works fine on a desktop, but on a phone or tablet it just shows a regular map?

This is profoundly annoying! - our location is notoriously difficult to find: we are on a leafy road in Birmingham and our use of signs is very tightly restricted by our landlords.

So I decided to embed a Google streetview onto the site as well as a Google map: then when I looked at it on a tablet it just displays the bloody map!

The page that it is happening on our site is [the Conference Park page](http://venuebirmingham.com/meet/conferencepark#tabset-tab-4)

Many thanks in advance to anyone who can shed any light onto this!

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is the fact that Street View is a Flash applet. Are you trying to view it under iOS?

Comment: Good point Jules: yes I am - but it also fails on Android too.

Comment: now you've planted the seed I've found a defintive statement on the subject [here](http://support.google.com/maps/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2819392)

Comment: looks like the only sane thing to do is to remove it; which is intensely annoying as it is explicitly intended to help mobile visitors find where to turn off the road!

Comment: Don't give up just yet. Many services, like [QSView](http://www.instantstreetview.com/), use the Maps API to offer a JS-powered Street View alternative.

Comment: Actually, @JamesRobinson, I just looked around the new Google Maps, and it looks like Street View is now entirely Flash-free. This probably comes with some amendments to the API, but it's still a huge leap forward in terms of compatibility.

Comment: Google now has Google Maps iOS SDK which has Street View. Works rather well

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing the point, it's easy enough to provide Streetview as an image - and it works fine on mobiles (iOS and Android).  Try something like this:

```
<img src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=[width without px]x[height without px]&location=[latitude],[longitude]&heading=[number of degrees - 0 = N]&fov=[number from 45 - 120 for degrees of field of vision]&sensor=false"/>
```

You can also, if it's required, provide a tilt argument to specify the elevation angle.  It's not draggable, but at least you can show the picture.

Answer (score 0):

Now Street View works on mobiles because they written an HTML5 version